# Is it possible to trigger intents in Dialogflow using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dialogflow-es

I want to hit an intent using python. In usual cases when a user says something, it goes to Dialogflow which via webhook send it to python. Is it possible that that python decides whether it goes to Dialogflow or not and also to trigger any specified intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes. You didn't specify which chat or voice agent platform you're using, but on all of them you can do something like this:

- Have the platform send the message to your python server. How it does this depends on each platform, but should be pretty well documented.
- Determine what the user has said - again, in a platform-dependent way.
- Determine if you want to send this on to Dialogflow. If you do, you use the Dialogflow API, calling the [/query](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query) endpoint (if you're using Dialogflow v1) or the [detectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) method (if you're using Dialogflow v2).
- Dialogflow will handle this as it always does, matching an intent and possibly calling the fulfillment if necessary. It will send you a reply.
- You turn the reply into something that the chat platform can handle and send that back.

Comment: If the answer helps you, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated. If you have a new question, you should ask it as a separate question on StackOverflow, not in the comments.